# read cells content of dataobject

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, data-objects

I read a csv file using javascript code and i want to push it into a a 2D Array in order to do some processing

```
var dataArray = new Array;
        function parseCSV(dataArray) {
            //replace UNIX new lines
            data = data.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
            //replace MAC new lines
            data = data.replace(/\r/g, "\n");
            //split into rows
            var rows = data.split("\n");

            // loop through all rows
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                // this line helps to skip empty rows
                if (rows[i]) {
                    // our columns are separated by comma
                    var column = rows[i].split(",");


                    var date=column[0];
                    var value = column[4];

                    // create object which contains all these items:
                    var dataObject = {
                        date: date,
                        T4: value 
                    };  
                   dataArray.push(dataObject);
                }
            }   
        } 
        }
```

As a test, i try to read a cell content and display on the web page to verify that i read the file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var x= dataArray[1][4];
        document.write(x);
    </script>
```

but it doesn't show anything.
Can anyone Help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dataArray = new Array;

var data = "Date,Description,Created By,Modified By,T4 Tag\n";
data += "20170424,This is record 1,user1,none,Just work please.\n";
data += "20170424,This is record 2,user2,none,I'm trying too.\n";

function parseCSV(dataArray) {
    //replace UNIX new lines
    data = data.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
    //replace MAC new lines
    data = data.replace(/\r/g, "\n");
    //split into rows
    var rows = data.split("\n");

    // loop through all rows
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // this line helps to skip empty rows
        if (rows[i]) {
            // our columns are separated by comma
            var column = rows[i].split(",");


            var date=column[0];
            var value = column[4];

            // create object which contains all these items:
            var dataObject = {
                date: date,
                T4: value 
            };  
           dataArray.push(dataObject);
        }
    }   
} 
parseCSV(dataArray);
```

Lacking a file, I forced some CSV data into a string for processing.
Your question is not showing these two items:

1. how you are setting **var data**
2. how you are calling **parseCSV(dataArray)**

If these two things are present all should work - [Here's the proof](https://repl.it/HXkv)

---

As far as the html script portion:

your array addressing looks wrong - it seems like it should look like:

```
<script>
  var x = dataArray[1].T4;
  document.write(x);
</script>
```

---

**Here's my reasoning**:

I understand that you are passing the CSV data to this function for parsing it into your dataArray variable - correct?

If correct, this data will look something like I have added manually (I added this directly just to work with something).

The bigger item is not so much where the data is coming from, but that ultimately it gets parsed by this parseCSV function.

When this happens, you are building appending to the empty **dataArray** variable in the following way:

For the first pass this will look as follows:

[{"date" : "Date", "T4" : "T4 Tag"}]

For the second pass:

[{"date" : "Date", "T4" : "T4 Tag"}, {"date" : "20170424", "T4" : "Just work please."}]

For the third pass:

[{"date" : "Date", "T4" : "T4 Tag"}, {"date" : "20170424", "T4" : "Just work please."}, {"date" : "20170424", "T4" : "I\'m trying too."}]

So now when you are in your html  section of code, you have no key of address **[4]**.

Your code says:

```
var x = dataArray[1][4];
```

Consider the following to see what I mean:

```
var record = dataArray[1];
//{"date" : "20170424", "T4" : "Just work please."}
//There is no key 4 here only date & T4.
var date = record.date;//returns: "20170424"
var t4 = record.T4;//returns: "Just work please."
```

**In Contrast if you had the following - your method would work**

```
myObj = {"date" : "20170424", "4" : "This is a value for field 4", "T4" : "Just work please."}
myObj[4];//returns "This is a value for field 4";
```

hopefully this explains it clearly enough.

Comment: I call a load csv function in which i call parsecsv

Comment: @S.ElBahloul, I think I found the culprit, please see the appended part of my answer and [This updated link](https://repl.it/HXkv/1).

Comment: It doesn't show anything. i shouldn't define data in the page because my app browse a csv file data, i try to show a cell content as a test so i can build some processing on some parameters using for loops

Answer (score 0):

here is the load csv file function

```
function loadCSV(file) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                var request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            // load
            request.open('GET', file, false);
            request.send();
            parseCSV(dataArray);
        }
```

Comment: What do you expect to have happen here? Do you expect parseCSV to be run with your server side response data after parsing a CSV? Is so, I would expect this to be empty as well, as you are not passing the request.responseText into parseCSV - like so parseCSV(request.responseText). Also you should really be checking your ready states before sending as well.

Comment: There is an even bigger problem here, and it has to do with your scoping of variable names. In your javascript file you call **dataArray** out as an empty array, and you don't define what **data** is. However you try to use **dataArray** as an input parameter to this function. It is already accessible to the function without you using this as a parameter because of its existence outside of the function. You are trying to instantiate this function via an ajax response, and instead of passing response data you are passing an empty array, then you try to populate this array from **data**.

Comment: I dont understand very well your explanation. all what i want is read the csv file, put data in 2D array so i can do some processing. for example. the second colum is T4 and i from 0 to rows.length is value of T4. if T4 surpass>750 over 30seconds (column0 is time ) there is a problem. do you see what i mean? can you give me a correct code for this??

Comment: This will depend on what the request.responseText returns. Is this a stringified JSON object, or is this a string similar to what I hardcoded into the `data` variable in my answer?

Comment: As you want just something that let me do processing

Comment: @RickRiggs I'm waiting for your help! i wanna some code to read the file (which is browsed) and put data in 2D array